# Is a crazy camel that lands on a normal camel's square placed under it, or over it?

Tags: untagged

In the game "Camel Up", a "crazy camel", moving backwards on on the racetrack, may land on a square where there is "normal camel".

When that happens, does the crazy camel go underneath the normal camel, or is it placed on top of it?

Comment: Do we really need a `camel-up-second-edition` tag? I think `camel-up` would suffice to cover everything about all editions of the game.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson that really depends on how different the editions are - some games editions are almost identical, other games significant differences happen between editions, that could be enough to make answers for the first edition not apply to later editions and vice versa. I don't know the game [tag:camel-up] so I can't really say which case applies here.

Comment: @Andrew : I deleted the second edition tag. I would think that tag useful once someone has flagged a question that requires a distinction between editions to be made; in other words, I prefer a precedent-based approach (which I call «english») to a predict every possible outcome approach (which I call «french»)...

Comment: @Andrew in this case, the editions are not worth the distinction. The second edition has some additions, but the overlap is largely the same (and compatible where it differs).

Comment: It's worth noting that the "crazy camel" does not appear in the first edition of Camel Up.

Comment: @robyaw : You are absolutely right - I stand corrected and apologise to Andrew. I will reinstate his tag for the second edition...

Comment: Again, though, the tag can cover all editions, even though the second edition has some additions. You don't need edition tags on, say, magic the gathering, even though new stuff gets introduced.

Answer (score 7):

The rules state:

> Should a camel unit ends its movement on a space with another camel unit, it jumps **on top** of that other unit.

And also later (not directly relevant but possibly helpful):

> If a crazy camel lands on a spectator tile, its movement is influenced in the same way, just in the opposite direction to the racing camels.

So the rules set out that the crazy camels move in the opposite direction to the other camels, but otherwise follow the same rules. So if it moves into the same space as another camel, it will go on top.